# How can I remove a flowfile or whole object with a null field using JoltTransformJson in Apache NiFi?

Tags: json, transform, apache-nifi, data-cleaning, jolt

How can I transform(remove in this case) flowfile if one of the fields of the object is null using JoltTransformJson processor in nifi

here below is my data.

emp.json:

```json
[
  {
    "Name" : "john Smith",
    "DOB" : "2000-07-14",
    "Salary" : 16000.0
  },
  {
    "Name" : "Sara Jacob",
    "DOB" : "2000-07-14",
    "Salary" : 12000.0
  },
  {
    "Name" : "Peter John",
    "DOB" : null,
    "Salary" : 20000.0
  },
  {
    "Name" : "Lia Poul",
    "DOB" : "2000-07-14",
    "Salary" : 18000.0
  }
]
```

I used **`SplitJSON`** processor to split the JSON File into multiple -separate FlowFiles and i connected the downstream with the **`JoltTransformJson`** processor. Next, I configured JoltTransformJson  as below:
Jolt Transformation DSL: chain
Jolt Specification:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "rowsToRemove": {
        "*": {
          "DOB": {
            "$null": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But this expression only removed the DOB field, not the whole object and Flowfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use **`JoltTransformJSON`** processor with the following transformation specs which contain ***notNull*** function that pricipally resolves the issue such as

```json
[
  { // produce a new attribute, namely "Nl" to check whether the DOB is null
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Nl": ["=notNull(@(1,DOB))", "NuLl"]
      }
    }
  },
  { // the following conditional spontaneously removes the object having "Nl" : "NuLl" pair
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Nl": {
          "NuLl": {
            "@2": "@3,Nl"
          },
          "*": {
            "@2": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the remaining "Nl" attributes
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Nl": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "DOB": {
          "*": {
            "@2": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).